# Javascript Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can i create a cookie by using javascript just for end of the browser session(ie,upto closing of current browser).My script is like follows;

```
function setCookie(c_name,c_value,c_expiredays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+c_expiredays);
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(c_value)+
    ((c_expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}

setCookie('gs_cookie','firstme',1600000);
```

How much value i need to pass instead of 1600000. Please help....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you dont set any expire time, the cookie will be deleted upon closing of the browser:

```
setCookie('gs_cookie','firstme');
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting `c_expiredays` to `0` (without quotes) should do the trick.