# Javascript events (like onload) repetitive - how to stop?

Tags: javascript, cookies, settings, dom-events, onload

I got an "intro" running on my site, but I don't want it to repeat for a certain amount of time.

How exactly do you set and define a cookie (or is there any better solution), to run something once a day/session/week, etc?

Comment: Do you use jQuery or any other JavaScript libraries?

Comment: An splash page intro that would display itself once every day, or a splash page intro that would display itself once every year?  What's the desired delay?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the cookie to expire one day/week from now to handle "once a day, week" scenarios. I don't know about "once a session" - how do you define a 'session' and when does it begin/end?

See [Stackoverflow -how to set cookie to expire in 1 hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794989/how-to-set-a-cookie-to-expire-in-1-hour-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

[Setting a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621171/javascript-cookie) is the most compatible way to do this.

See the [MDC `document.cookie` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) for the full story.